# Label color based on label value

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10

I have a container with the labels like this...
But if the Label value is negative i need to Add Red color otherwise Green color. How can i do it in BB 10 cascades in Qml.

```
Container {
    leftPadding: 15.0
    rightPadding: 15.0
    layout: StackLayout {
        orientation: LayoutOrientation.LeftToRight
    }
    topPadding: 20.0

    Label {
        id: symbol
        text: ListItemData.Symbol_En

        // Text Style and size etc
        textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.SubtitleText
        textStyle.fontSizeValue: 30.0
        layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
            spaceQuota: 4
        }
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

    }
    Label {
        id: change
        text: ListItemData.PerChange
        textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.SubtitleText
        textStyle.fontSizeValue: 30.0
        layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
            spaceQuota: 2
        }
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

    }
    Label {
        id: ltp
        text: ListItemData.LTP
        textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.SubtitleText
        textStyle.fontSizeValue: 30.0
        layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
            spaceQuota: 1
        }
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

    }
    Label {
        id: highValue
        text: ListItemData.High
        textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.SubtitleText
        textStyle.fontSizeValue: 30.0
        layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
            spaceQuota: 1
        }
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

    }
    Label {
        id: lowValue
        text: ListItemData.Low
        textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.SubtitleText
        textStyle.fontSizeValue: 30.0
        layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
            spaceQuota: 1
        }
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center

    }
```

Comment: Which label do you want colored? And which value?

Comment: Label with id highValue. and if it is a negative i need Red color ,Green otherwise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about something like this (just the Label in question):

```
Label {
        id: highValue
        text: ListItemData.High
        textStyle.color: ListItemData.High.indexOf("-") < 0 ? Color.Green : Color.Red 
        textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.SubtitleText
        textStyle.fontSizeValue: 30.0
        layoutProperties: StackLayoutProperties {
            spaceQuota: 1
        }
        verticalAlignment: VerticalAlignment.Center
        horizontalAlignment: HorizontalAlignment.Center
    }
```

Comment: But here ListItemData.High is a QString. Is it possible to compare like  ListItemData.High.contains('-') ? Color.Red : Color.Green

Comment: How about you use parseInt. I added it in

Comment: istead of .contains you can use .indexOf("-") > 0. If there is "-" inside you will get 0, otherwise you get -1

Comment: ListItemData.High.indexOf("-") <0 ? Color.Red : Color.Green  gives me always red in colored label. Even for QString that not containing '-' Symbol

Comment: Try and print out data, see what you get. I tested this, and is works! `.indexOf("-") < 0 ? Color.Green : Color.Red`

Comment: yes dear, Me too used the index-of trick, it is Showing the Labels in only red color :) now i tested with  ListItemData.High.indexOf('-') <0 ? Color.Green : Color.Red , rather than  ListItemData.High.indexOf('-') <0 ?  Color.Red :Color.Green , Thjis time I get Only Green color Labels

Comment: yeah,i got the same values what i send ,on the Simulator!!! It all the values with either red or green color !!!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/izPz1xRM this is a working example. If you use similar to this then I don't know what the problem is

Comment: Thanks man It's working !!! can i get your email id i have cople of questions in my mind, I am new to BB 10 cascades !!! I don't let disturb your privacy!!! i need truly a guide to move further with bb 10 cascades !!! Waiting for youe reply.

Comment: Just ask on StackOverflow, I'm checking blackberry-10 tag all the time.